# Pipes and Redirection, small program to test understanding

Tags: c

I have written a small program called "blah" which takes stdin chars and outputs uppercase chars to stdout, see below (NOTE: the code immediately below works as desired):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char input[500];
printf( "BLAH HAS STARTED OK......\n");
while (!feof(stdin)){
    fprintf(stderr, "startloop\n");
    input[0]=0;
    fprintf(stderr, "blocking for input !\n");
    fgets(input, 500, stdin);
    fprintf(stderr, "finished blocking for input !\n");
    int index=0;
    while (input[index]!='\n' && input[index]!=0 ){
        printf("%c", input[index]-32);
        index++;
    }
    if (index==0){
        break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "endloop\n");
}
printf("BLAH CLOSED.....\n");
return 0;
}
```

And another program which makes a pipe for parent to child communication, and also a pipe for child to parent communication. The process then forks a child, the stdin of the child process redirected to the output end of the parent write pipe and the stdout of the child process redirected to the input end of the parent read pipe. Since blah work as expected running by itself, I expected the test written to the parent write pipe to come back in capitals. Could someone explain what is wrong with my understanding?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int fds1[2];
    int fds2[2];
    pipe(fds1);
    pipe(fds2);
    int pid=fork();
    if (pid) {
    /* parent*/
    close(fds1[0]);
    close(fds2[1]);
    char val[100];
    FILE* parentwrite=fdopen(fds1[1], "w");
    FILE* parentread=fdopen(fds2[0], "r");
    fprintf(parentwrite, "this text should be printed in capitals\n");
    while (!feof(parentread)){
        fgets(val, 100, parentread);
        printf("PARENT PRINTING TEXT FROM CHILD: %s\n", val);
    }
    }
    else 
    {
    /*child*/
    close(fds1[1]);
    close(fds2[0]);
    dup2(fds1[0],0);
    dup2(fds2[1],1);
    execlp("./blah", "./blah", 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pls note the fprints to stderr are just to help me try understand what is happening - I am relatively new to C

Comment: You have pasted a big block of code and said *what is wrong with my understanding?*. What is the code supposed to do, what does it actually do? Your problem isnt clear ...

Comment: i will amend my post, thank you for the feedback

Comment: While you are at it, indent your code correctly.

Comment: what is meant by 'indent your code correctly' is:  indent after every opening brace '{' (suggest 4 spaces as that does not eat up the page width and is visible even with variable width fonts)  un-indent before every closing brace '}'   Do not use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   For readability, it  is also a very good practice to separate code blocks (like do...while, for(), while() ) by a blank line.  While code can be 'self documenting'  the posted code is not, so a key comment here and there is very helpful

Comment: this is wrong: `if (pid) {
    /* parent*/` because fork() can also return a -1 when an error occurs and the posted code will think the fork() was successful and that the current execution is the parent

Comment: a pid is `pid_t`, (not necessarily an integer) as defined in: #include <unistd.h>

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the code.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand and a real headache to maintain.  Suggest: use #define or enum to define the values, with meaningful names and use those meaningful names throughout the code.  Note: by common practice, 0 and 1 do not need to be #define'd/part of a enum

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be `fdopen`ing after `pipe()` in your parent process. Just write/read, `pipe()` returns opened file descriptors, that's why you can close them

Answer (score 0):

in general, using `feof()` for loop control is a bad idea as that only is set 'true' AFTER trying to read past the end of the input stream.

suggest using the `fgets()` statement in the `while()` statement for loop control.   Similar to:

```
fprintf(stderr, "startloop\n");
while ( fgets(input, sizeof( input ), stdin) )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "finished blocking for input !\n");

    for( index 0; input[index]!='\n' && input[index]!='\0'; index++ )
    {
        printf("%c", input[index]-32);
        //printf("%c", input[index]-32); // ??? 32 is a space, relatively meaningless in this scenario
    } // end for

    printf("\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "endloop\n");
} // end while
```